# When doing forward declarations, is there a difference between not naming the parameter and naming it?

Tags: c++

In C++ when you have multiple functions declared in the same file and need to forward declare them, is there a difference between doing:

```
void function(string parameter_name)
```

and

```
void function(string)
```

If there is no difference, why is there an option to do it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference to the compiler, but including the name can improve
code readability.

Comment: And in some cases, omitting it can help too.